# UIActivityViewController on iPad weird behavior, App not optimized

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

My app isn't optimized for iPad but before iOS 7, UIActivityViewController was working perfectly (same behavior on both devices).

I mean, it works now, but some icons are strange and others are missing.

Screenshot:

[image: UIActivityViewController on iPad]

I'm presenting UIActivityViewController this way:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add some of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 7. Due to the upscaling of an iPhone app to iPad, Apple is accommodating for the resizing of some parts of the UI but not others.

There is no way to fix this as it is one of Apple's own controls.

I'd recommend trying this out in iOS 8 and seeing if it has been fixed.

Comment: Update for those facing the same issue: I still see it in iOS 8.1.2.

Comment: In iOS 8.2, the issue hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Still observed in iOS 8.3 :(

Comment: anyone find any solution?